# Can event value be a dimension?

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics, event-tracking

I think I saw before below `Event Category`, `Event Action` and `Event Label`, there was `Event Value`. Now there is no. Can this be the case?

[image]

My events have category, action, label and value that is integer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The event value is an integer. Generally when you can do mathematical operations on a data field (event values add up) it is a metric rather than a dimension. If you try to send a string as event value you'll see an error in the GA debugger and most likely your event tracking will fail.

Event value is in fact supposed to be a currency (which does not quite work out, since it does not accept decimal numbers). The idea is to express the value of events that are not transactions as monetary value.

You could store a (stringified) version of the event value in a custom dimension. It would not by default appear in standard reports, you'd have to select it as secondary dimension or use is as a custom report. Also the values would no longer be added up.

Comment: this looks very good and throughout. re the currency can the event label store the value, say category money, action receipt, label "$20.332,99" and then value to be just 2033299 that is a notation, counting two decimal points. I guess Google supports big integers?

Comment: however I think I saw somewhere `Event Value`, as described in the quest, if I am lucky I may get that document again.

Comment: @prosti, you cannot, by definition, use a metric as a dimension. You can store the metric value in a custom dimension field, but that will behave differently. As for the other question, the field reference for analytics.js does not specify a max length for the "event value" field so I'd say yes, they support pretty big integers.